# How to fix python-selenium crash when trying to make a screenshot?

Tags: python, selenium

Using selenium 4.0.0 for python, I am getting an error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: session deleted because of page crash
from unknown error: cannot determine loading status
from tab crashed
  (Session info: headless chrome=94.0.4606.81)
```

when the code tries to make a screenshot. The traceback is

```
  ...
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/check_pages/page_dom_check.py", line 57, in make_full_screenshot
    img = Image.open(BytesIO((driver.get_screenshot_as_png())))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 1064, in get_screenshot_as_png
    return base64.b64decode(self.get_screenshot_as_base64().encode('ascii'))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 1074, in get_screenshot_as_base64
    return self.execute(Command.SCREENSHOT)['value']
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
```

I cannot post a small reproducible code, as it only happens when I run this  within a gitlab CI. But it happens always when the screenshot is being made.

Maybe there is another way to make a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

I have no answer to my question, but I created a workaround that seems to work.

I was creating a selenium driver, and that single driver was opening different pages. Here I got the error.

```
# pseudocode
driver = ...
for check in checks:
    driver.get(url)
    # do other stuff with driver
driver.quit()
```

To work around this problem, create a new driver for each page individually.

```
# pseudocode
for check in checks:
    driver = ...
    driver.get(url)
    # do other stuff with driver
    driver.quit()
```

That way you can even put all the stuff around the driver in a try-except loop to try again

```
# pseudocode
for check in checks:
    while ...
        try:
            driver = ...
            driver.get(url)
            # do other stuff with driver
            driver.quit()
        except UselessException:
            pass
```